# JTable change position of other components on BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

My problem is that when I add JTable to panel all other components are moved to right side for about 20% of panel lenght, code is:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("my frame");

JPanel panel = new JPanel();
BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS);
panel.setLayout(layout);

JButton but1 = new JButton("button1");
but1.setAligmentX(0);
panel.add(but1);

String[] columnNames = {"kolumna 1", "kol 2", "kol3"};
JTable itemTable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 10));
panel.add(new JScrollPane(itemTable));

JButton but2 = new JButton("button2");
but2.setAligmentX(0);
panel.add(but2);

frame.setContentPane(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

and the result is

```
    button1
TABLEEEEEEE
TABLEEEEEEE
TABLEEEEEEE
TABLEEEEEEE
    button2
```

instead of

```
button1
TABLEEEEEE
TABLEEEEEE
TABLEEEEEE
TABLEEEEEE
button2
```

what am i doing wrong?

/edit

i checked that JTextArea is fine, but JScrollPane and JTable cause this problem, used button with .setAligment(0) method but same result

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
    JButton b1 = new JButton("button1");
    String[] columnNames = { "kolumna 1", "kol 2", "kol3" };
    JTable itemTable = new JTable(new DefaultTableModel(columnNames, 10));
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(itemTable);

    JButton b2 = new JButton("button2");

    b1.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    scrollPane.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);
    b2.setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(panel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS);
    panel.setLayout(layout);

    panel.add(b1);
    panel.add(scrollPane);
    panel.add(b2);
```

There is more inforamtion here : [java BoxLayout panel's alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212155/java-boxlayout-panels-alignment)

Comment: thank you a lot, scrollPane.setAligmentX(0) worked, can you exaplain me what happened?

Comment: you need to set the JScrollPane alignment not the Jtable :)