# JLabel not aligned to the left

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

My JLabel hudHeader isn't aligned to left.

Here is what it looks like at the moment:
[image]

HUDisplay extends JPanel.

```
public HUDisplay() {

Border border = BorderFactory.createMatteBorder(0, 1, 0, 0, new Color(128, 128, 128));
Border margin = new EmptyBorder(8,8,8,8);
setBorder(new CompoundBorder(border, margin));
setBackground(new Color(250,250,250));

setLayout(new BoxLayout(this, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));


hudHeader = new JLabel("<html><b>Simulation informations</b><br />" +
        "<i style=\"font-size: 8px;\">Running for " + "0" + "s</i>" + "</html>");

hSeparation = new JSeparator(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL);

add(hudHeader);
add(hSeparation);

setVisible(true);

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9212155/java-boxlayout-panels-alignment as BoxLayout centers

Comment: I already tried, nothing changes with the following lines :-(
setMaximumSize( new Dimension(  200, 600) );
setAlignmentX(Component.LEFT_ALIGNMENT);

Comment: It is mere adding JPanels. That will become stretched over the entire width, and then one can add a label left aligned in the panel.

Comment: That looks like `<html><body style='margin: 0 0 0 0'>` which actually was my first impulse.

Comment: When I setMaximumSize and setAlignementX on HUDisplay (JPanel), the JLabel is still aligned to the "center". I don't know if the body's style property is a suggestion but it doesn't work aswell :-(

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOT SO: It looks like an HTML body margin

```
NOT hudHeader = new JLabel(
NOT         "<html><body style='margin: 0 0 0 0;'><b>Simulation informations</b><br />" +
NOT         "<i style=\"font-size: 8px;\">Running for " + "0" + "s</i>" + "</html>");
```

However there might be something fishy, like RTL, so try too

```
hudHeader .setAlignment(SwingConstants.LEFT);
```

Comment: It works with the second option. I was using Component.LEFT_ALIGNEMENT instead of SwingConstants.LEFT. Thanks for your help.